# Material causing outline on Mesh

Tags: materials, uv

I'm trying to UV map on a different section on my model. So I separated the mesh, and assign the same material which I made, just under a different name because it's already using a UV image on another section of my model. Once I add the UV image, I adjust it accordingly but its causing some type of border which I can see. Where is this coming from?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). There's no need to separate the mesh - just add another material slot and assign the material. This looks like normals issue, caused by the separation.

Comment: I wanted the bottom section where it's green to have the same material like the above. So I duplicated the material and all the nodes were the same. So I tried to put another UV image texture in the green section. And because the nodes were the same, it would delete on the above image RED section too, I thought that by making a duplicate of the same material  wouldn't affect the faces I choose but it was getting affected the whole mesh. So I separated the section and use new material and add the same UV and it wouldnt affect the rest of the mesh.

https://ibb.co/NYzVHmr